# Как заполнить базу данных ответом пользователя через бота телеграм?

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Я новичок и пишу бота для телеграм, но не могу найти информацию про то как заполнить столбец в базе данных ответом пользователя которое ввёл через бота. Использую sqlite3 и telebot. Буду благодарен за информацию.

Comment: дополните вопрос своим кодом.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import sqlite3
    con = sqlite3.connect('путь к бд')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('UPDATE {имя таблицы} SET {имя столбца} = {данные} WHERE {столбец с идентификацией пользователя, например id} = {значение}')
    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

Это при условии, что таблица в базе данных уже создана. Если нет, то:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE название_таблицы (название_столбца тип, название тип);")
con.commit()
con.close()
cur.close()
```

Почитайте подробнее про SQL запросы, документацию sqlite. Как получить данные от пользователя, Вы, надеюсь, знаете.